# How to solve mysql nested query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query and output. Now i try to count total sum of unique item_id and name with this

```
SELECT name, SUM(item_id) 
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM items U
      JOIN users_items UI ON UI.item_id = U.id)
```

but it shows error

[image]

Comment: i advice you to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. Images are not considerd a good source off data.

Comment: "but it shows error" I don't see a error in the image? Atleast not a SQL error.

Comment: picture contain only (SELECT *
      FROM items U
      JOIN users_items UI ON UI.item_id = U.id) this query output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you find something below

```
 select name, sum(item_id) FROM items U
 JOIN users_items UI ON UI.item_id = U.id
 group  by name
```

Comment: This query is in fact **invalid** ANSI SQL.. You can't mix a non aggregated column with a aggregated column like this.. "Query Error: Error: ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a6W865Kaa669Rt3fKLnJZi/0)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the sum of unique `item_id`s, you need to use `DISTINCT` with the `SUM`:

```
 SELECT 
   name, 
   SUM(DISTINCT item_id) 
 FROM items U
 JOIN users_items UI 
   ON UI.item_id = U.id
```

Comment: This query is in fact **invalid** ANSI SQL.. You can't mix a non aggregated column with a aggregated column like this.. "Query Error: Error: ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a6W865Kaa669Rt3fKLnJZi/0)

Answer (score 0):

Because you need an alias for the subquery and a group by expression as `group by name`

```
SELECT q.name, SUM(q.item_id) 
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM items U
      JOIN users_items UI ON UI.item_id = U.id) q
GROUP BY q.name
```

Answer (score 0):

A unique COUNT of the items per user would make more sense than a unique SUM of the items per item.

```
SELECT usr.name as user_name, COUNT(DISTINCT uitem.item_id) AS TotalUniqueItems
FROM users AS usr
JOIN users_items AS uitem ON uitem.user_id = usr.id
GROUP BY usr.id, usr.name
ORDER BY usr.name
```

Or the reverse, a unique count of users per item

```
SELECT item.name as item_name, COUNT(DISTINCT uitem.user_id) AS TotalUniqueUsers
FROM items AS item
JOIN users_items AS uitem ON uitem.item_id = item.id
GROUP BY item.id, item.name
ORDER BY item.name
```

Comment: @AYANADHIKARY Cool. And you could still add a SUM if you want, but then do it for the "price".  And perhaps change the Approval, because I doubt the current one with the SUM does what you expect.